# trouble understanding Popcorn.js timeupdate function as it is not working in certain cases

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, popcornjs

**Why is the 1st block of code working while the 2nd one is not**?? --

The following code works:-

```
// this code works --

<script src=".../popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>

    var time_prompts = new Array();
    time_prompts[0] = 2  //any integer < video duration

      $popcorn.on( "timeupdate", function() {
          console.log( this.currentTime() );
          if (this.currentTime() > time_prompts[0] && this.currentTime() < time_prompts[0]+0.1) {
              this.pause();
              console.log(this.paused)
          }  
      });
```

While the following code doesn't work:-

```
// this code DOES NOT work

    <script src=".../popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>

        var time_prompts = new Array();
        time_prompts[0] = 2  //any integer < video duration

          $popcorn.on( "timeupdate", function() {
              console.log( this.currentTime() );
              if (this.currentTime() == time_prompts[0]) {
                  this.pause();
                  console.log(this.paused)
              }  
          });
```

( **The only difference between the 2** code blocks **is the 'if statement' (condition)** )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `this.currentTime()` is not an integer. It is a `Number` containing a floating point value. As you can see in the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/popcornjs/a3TGF/), provided in the [documentation](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/media-methods/#currentTime), it is unlikely to get a round integer value. So checking for equality is inappropriate in this case. You did not specify what did you want to achieve with your code, but if you want to pause the video after it reaches 2 second in play, you should check if `currentTime` is greater than 2, and then set a variable that will ensure you do this only once:

```
var time_prompts = [], once = true;
time_prompts[0] = 2  //any integer < video duration

  $popcorn.on( "timeupdate", function() {
      console.log( this.currentTime() );
      if (this.currentTime() > time_prompts[0] && once) {
          once = false;
          this.pause();
          console.log(this.paused)
      }  
  });
```

Comment: actually there are multiple times the video has to be paused and the `time_prompts` are fed by a server-side program based on certain conditions.....I had removed those parts of the code that were unnecessary to the current context....I was just wondering why I the 2nd piece of code was failing while the 1st 1 not... thanks anyways, this explains my doubt!:)